# Find the range k can take if $kx^2 + (k -3)x + 1$ has distinct, positive roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of roots is $-\frac{k-3}k$ and the product is $\frac1k$. Obviously, the sum and product are greater than $0$, and $k\ne0$. then solving for $k$ in the sum gives $k < 3$.

I don't get the answer in the book, $0<k<1$. can someone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: you've only constrained $k$ with the roots' sum, not their product.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean lol. product is c/a = 1/k???

Comment: You're given the roots are positive, so their product is too, i.e. $1/k>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$, $b$ be the roots
$$a+b=\frac{3-k}{k}$$ and $$a.b=\frac{1}{k}$$
from second condition you get:  $k>0$
, using this in first condition we get: $$k<3$$

Further we have the discriminant condition, $$B^2-4AC>0$$

which gives $$k\in(-\infty,1)\cup(9,\infty)$$

Finally the intersection of the feasible values of k gives us: $$k\in(0,1)$$

Comment: In the step before last you use Union sign not intersection sign.

Comment: @NoChance acc to my calculation it should be union only

Comment: But union leads to full range Not just (0,1).

Comment: @NoChance I have written intersection in the last step. Not taking union